# How To Insert Data in Hosting Database Using VB.NET

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, vb.net, web-services

I've a Hosting that contains mysql database, and i simply want to insert data into that database but using VB.NET.

Ex :

> There's a Textbox and a button, when click on button is performed the value from that textbox have to be inserted in database of hosting.

What service or functions should i use??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim Conn As New ADODB.Connection
Conn.ConnectionString = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};SERVER=" & server & ";DATABASE=" & database & ";UID=" & user & ";PWD=" & pass & ";PORT=" & port & ";"
Conn.Open()
Conn.Execute("insert into tblname (fld1,fld2) values('"& textVal &"',"& numericVal &")")
Conn.Close()
Conn = Nothing
```

Paste in .vb file and edit connectionstring & insert string.
Good luck..

Comment: And; add COM reference Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.x Library